# MS Sql Query slows down when adding just one more row to LIMIT keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I'm having a weird issue on my query. I'm not that experienced in writing SQL
Queries, but I'm not a total newbie either.
This one keeps me thinking and searching for an hour at least.

Query I tried (`SELECT TOP (19785)..`) (numbers are important) executes in around 15 ms, but  the same query with top increased just by 1 executes 434 ms.
Can someone explain why this happens?

I've attached screenshot below, so you can see what I'm talking about if I didn't explain well.

[image: Image url - click here]

EDIT:
Also, forgot to mention that this table is really simple, it has no foreign keys, and no other complex field other than two decimals(for storing latitude and longitude)

EDIT2: Attached the query execution plan below.
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1PLtgkSN

EDIT3:
Sorry for making mistake this obvious, but I noticed that table actually has foreign key, for the country.
Also, I noticed that if I removed TOP(N) and uniqueidentifier(guid) field and then re-did both queries with

```
ORDER BY Id OFFSET M ROWS
FETCH NEXT N ROWS ONLY;
```

it shows similar execution time (~15 ms)

It shows that I should do queries in chunks, which isn't that much of an issue, considering I'm supposed to have pagination in the app I'm working on.

Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

Comment: Have you looked at the query plan (`EXPLAIN ...`)? Most likely the cost of (not) using a certain index is what brings your query over the limit. Either rescan the indices/query costs to make them correspond to your data or force the "good" index using a query hint.

Comment: Would you be that kind to tell me just where I'm supposed to start, and I'll do the research?
I'm not that good with indexes and rescanning their costs.

Comment: Can you try the same query with option(recompile) for both values. Next, would you try rebuilding the indexes.

Comment: Time statistics aren't useful. Display and compare the execution plans (Ctrl+L will show you the estimated execution plan). Use `statistics IO on` to see what IO was actually performed for each query

Comment: Please provide us the query plans for both cases. You can do this by pressing "Include actual execution plan" (or Ctrl_M). Then run your query, go to the execution plan pane of the output section, use save as, and copy-paste the xml to a site like pastetheplan.com . Then, give us the links.

Comment: Hit `Ctrl+M` to include the actual execution plan in the results and compare the two queries

Comment: Here's the plan link:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1PLtgkSN

Comment: Please consider that: a) CPU time is equivalent, b) plan shows equal cost of two queries. How many attempts you did? What will became: a) if you change the order of `SELECT`s, b) run them in different sessions?

Comment: I tried re-arranging select, also, I tried to run them separately, and I'm still getting similar results.
I did index fragmentation check (as Corion and Cetin said) and it's below 1%. 
I tried rearrange and rebuild options, and nothing noticeable changed.

Also, I see what you said about resource usage, that's what makes this more puzzling to me. I'd understand if there was some sort of issue with indexes, but now...

Answer (score 0):

This could be the effect of row goal targets, (see: https://sqlperformance.com/2018/02/sql-plan/setting-and-identifying-row-goals). This is where SQL Server uses the value of TOP (n) in it's consideration for how it will physically retrieve data. Typically SQL Server will use the distribution of data to be retrieved by the query and the indexes available to determine the retrieval pattern.